# Proving that a particular linear map is an isomorphism- definite integrals and powers of x

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The problem was given as follows:

Define the map $M$ : $P_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by $M(p) = (m_0(p), m_1(p), ..., m_n(p))$, where $m_j(p) = \int_0^1x^jp(x)dx$.

Here, $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of polynomial functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with degree at most $n$.

Prove that $M$ is an isomorphism.

---

There was also a hint given, which I have not been able to make use of so far: "If $M(p) = 0$, find a linear combination of the elements $m_j(p)$ that can be used to deduce $p = 0$.

---

What I have been doing so far is just to write out more explicitly what each $m_j(p)$ is, and expanding upon them with the notation $p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_nx^n$. I have been combining them in all sorts of ways to no avail, and I am just wondering if it is maybe simpler than I am thinking of.

Any hints or suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Assume that $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$.

Then $a_0m_0(p)+a_1m_1(p)+\cdots+a_nm_n(p)=\int_0^1p(x)^2\mathrm{d}x$.

What is the left hand side if $M(p)=0$ ? Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah I can figure it out now, and finally get some sleep! Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Good night, then  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If $M(p)=0$, then $m_0(p)=m_1(p)=\dots=m_n(p)=0$.  Thus *any* linear combination of the $m_i$ is zero.

Now write $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_nx^n$.

Then consider the linear combination $0=a_0m_0(p)+a_1m_1(p)+\dots+a_nm_n(p)=\int_0^1(p)^2\operatorname dx$.